# twilio-cli *.so dependencies not in centos 7.9 repo

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

When I use yum to local install twilio-cli I get the following dependency errors:

```
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.28)(64bit) for package: twilio-5.16.1-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.27)(64bit) for package: twilio-5.16.1-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.9)(64bit) for package: twilio-5.16.1-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.20)(64bit) for package: twilio-5.16.1-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.21)(64bit) for package: twilio-5.16.1-1.el8.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: twilio-5.16.1-1.el8.x86_64 (/twilio-5.16.1-1.el8.x86_64)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.9)(64bit)
Error: Package: twilio-5.16.1-1.el8.x86_64 (/twilio-5.16.1-1.el8.x86_64)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.28)(64bit)
Error: Package: twilio-5.16.1-1.el8.x86_64 (/twilio-5.16.1-1.el8.x86_64)
           Requires: libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.27)(64bit)
Error: Package: twilio-5.16.1-1.el8.x86_64 (/twilio-5.16.1-1.el8.x86_64)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.25)(64bit)
Error: Package: twilio-5.16.1-1.el8.x86_64 (/twilio-5.16.1-1.el8.x86_64)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.20)(64bit)
Error: Package: twilio-5.16.1-1.el8.x86_64 (/twilio-5.16.1-1.el8.x86_64)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.21)(64bit)
```

Makes sense, given the **el8** in "twilio-5.16.1-1.el8.x86_64"

I'm on centos 7.9 `Linux p6t 3.10.0-1160.102.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Oct 11 09:21:06 CDT 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

I have no choice: I have to get this running natively on this machine if at all possible.

I'm thinking about grabbing proper versions of those files listed above and putting them in a directory added to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to make them available to the twilio-cli executable.

Before I tell my boss that the above is my plan of my attack, I'm asking on stackoverflow: **Is there any reason to think this approach won't work at all.**

Comment: So recompile twilio-cli from source? Use docker? nix?

Comment: needs to run native on that machine.  the machine os level may not be increased. I just want to know if i snag the right files, will they work on that machine.

Comment: Yes, so compile twilio-cli from source, use podman or install from nix. Nix-env does _exactly_ what you want to do.  Also appimage. There were just hundreds of programmers with the same idea, who already streamlined it. What is "machine os level"?

Comment: "os level" - sorry for inventing a term. The machine is stuck on 7.9, and moving to 8+ is not an option. Would prefer to not go down another rabbit hole with a compilation and related. Was thinking of snagging the files from an el8 package and just chucking them in. Why would that idea be inferior to building the program I need to run?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question:

> Is there any reason to think this approach won't work at all.

Prevalent, most of the time, it works.

There is a very slim chance you might encounter some [incompatibilities in kernel](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/69663) and this happens from time to time, especially that your kernel is quite old.